# Question on a parameter $\alpha_1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Assume that $\alpha_1>0, \alpha_2>0, t_1 \in R, t_2 \in R$.

Does the validity of the  equality

$\int_0^1(-1)^xx^{-\alpha_1-it_1}dx/\int_0^1(-1)^xx^{-\alpha_2-it_2}dx=0$

implies that $\alpha_1=1/2$?

P.S. We can assume in addition that $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$.